# Typo3 News Extension: "TypoScript object path "lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering" does not exist"

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-news, typo3-10.x

Without knowingly having changed something in the configuration or templates, I can't output content elements in the detail view of news-articles.

```
1/1) #1253191023 TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception

TypoScript object path "lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering" does not exist
```

I have this configuration:

**typo3conf/ext/news/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt**

```
# Rendering of content elements in detail view
lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering = RECORDS
lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering {
    tables = tt_content
    source.current = 1
    dontCheckPid = 1
}
```

**typo3conf/ext/site_package/Resources/Plugin/News/Templates/News/Detail.html**

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.contentElements}">
 <!-- content elements -->
 <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">
  {newsItem.contentElementIdList}
 </f:cObject>
</f:if>
```

So it looks to me as it is what is recommended in the docs: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/Tutorials/Templates/RenderContentElements/Index.html

**Typo3 version: 10.4.12**

**News version: 8.5.2**

I can't figure out why I can't output content-elements in news-articles all of the sudden.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please mention your TYPO3 and News version.

Comment: Typo3 10.4.12
News 8.5.2

Comment: Have you included the static TypoScript of EXT:news in your (TypoScript-)Template? https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/Installation/Index.html#preparation-include-static-typoscript

Comment: You are right, the static template was not included... Thank you. How can I award this question to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering`is not defined, most likely you've forgotten to include the static TypoScript Template of EXT:news.

[News system - Installation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/Installation/Index.html#preparation-include-static-typoscript):

> Preparation: Include static TypoScript
>
> The extension ships some TypoScript code which needs to be included.
>
> 1. Switch to the root page of your site.
> 2. Switch to the Template module and select Info/Modify.
> 3. Press the link Edit the whole template record and switch to the tab Includes.
> 4. Select News (news) at the field Include static (from extensions):
>    [image: Screenshot of TYPO3 backend's "Include static" field]